# Изменения классов JS

Tags: javascript

При изменении `class="main main-active"`, `block active` меняется в диве `main`, а не `main-active`. Как исправить что бы `active` в `div.block` изменялся в `main-active`, а не в первом элементе `main`?

```js
var main_active = document.querySelector('.main-active'),
  btn_blocks = document.querySelector('.btn-blocks'),
  btn_main = document.querySelector('.btn-main'),
  blocks = Array.from(main_active.querySelectorAll('.block')),
  main = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.main')),
  pointer = 0;
pointer_main = 0;

btn_blocks.addEventListener('click', function() {
  blocks[pointer].classList.remove('active');
  if (pointer + 1 >= blocks.length)
    pointer = 0;
  else
    pointer++;
  blocks[pointer].classList.add('active');
});

btn_main.addEventListener('click', function() {
  main[pointer_main].classList.remove('main-active');
  if (pointer_main + 1 >= main.length)
    pointer_main = 0;
  else
    pointer_main++;
  main[pointer_main].classList.add('main-active');
});
```

```html
<button class="btn-blocks">button blocks</button>
<br>
<button class="btn-main">button main</button>
<div class="main main-active">
  <div class="block red active"></div>
  <div class="block black"></div>
  <div class="block green"></div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="block red active"></div>
  <div class="block black"></div>
  <div class="block green"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b6312wvt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, можно при переключении `main-active` переопределять переменные `main_active` и `blocks`, над которыми делается манипуляция.

```js
btn_main.addEventListener('click', function() {
  main[pointer_main].classList.remove('main-active');
  if (pointer_main + 1 >= main.length)
    pointer_main = 0;
  else
    pointer_main++;
  main[pointer_main].classList.add('main-active');

  // look here
  main_active = document.querySelector('.main-active')
  blocks = Array.from(main_active.querySelectorAll('.block'))
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Суть вашей проблемы в том, что функции вроде `querySelector` не отслеживают изменения классов. Они возвращают соответствующие элементы на момент вызова.

Поэтому, вам необходимо, каким-либо образом обновлять ссылки(переменные) на активные элементы.

*Также замечу, что вы не можете иметь общий `pointer` для нескольких блоков.

В сниппете я получаю текущую позицию активного элемента с помощью `indexOf`.*

```js
var btn_blocks = document.querySelector('.btn-blocks'),
  btn_main = document.querySelector('.btn-main');

btn_blocks.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var main = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.main'));
  var main_active = document.querySelector('.main-active'); 
  var blocks = Array.from(main_active.querySelectorAll('.block'));
  var block_active = main_active.querySelector('.block.active');
  var pointer = blocks.indexOf(block_active);
  
 blocks[pointer].classList.remove('active');
  if (pointer + 1 >= blocks.length)
    pointer = 0;
  else
    pointer++;
  blocks[pointer].classList.add('active');
});

btn_main.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var main = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.main'));
  var main_active = document.querySelector('.main-active'); 
  var pointer_main = main.indexOf(main_active);
  
  main[pointer_main].classList.remove('main-active');
  if (pointer_main + 1 >= main.length)
    pointer_main = 0;
  else
    pointer_main++;
  main[pointer_main].classList.add('main-active');
});
```

```css
.red{background-color: red;}
.black{background-color: black;}
.green{background-color: green;}

.main{display: inline-block;}

.main-active{outline: 5px solid yellow;}
.active{outline: 5px solid blue; outline-offset: -5px;}

.block{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-blocks">button blocks</button>
<br>
<button class="btn-main">button main</button>
<hr/>
<div class="main main-active">
  <div class="block red active"></div>
  <div class="block black"></div>
  <div class="block green"></div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="block red active"></div>
  <div class="block black"></div>
  <div class="block green"></div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="block red active"></div>
  <div class="block black"></div>
  <div class="block green"></div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="block red active"></div>
  <div class="block black"></div>
  <div class="block green"></div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="block red active"></div>
  <div class="block black"></div>
  <div class="block green"></div>
</div>
```